# Can I build multiple projects with Maven and then run Jetty through m2eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a multi-module project which has a war and multiple jar dependencies. I'd like to be able to build multiple projects (the dependencies) and then launch the war in jetty with a single command. Is this possible? I'd normally make a script to do this, e.g.

```
mvn clean install
cd project-web/
mvn jetty:run
cd ..
```

However, this loses the Debug functionality from Eclipse. Is there a way to do this in m2eclipse?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't `Run As...` -> `Run on Server` in eclipse? I've had issues using the Debug view via m2e; it generally has issues finding the source for my applications.

Comment: I like Maven because it's a repeatable build process (i.e. I know my team are all doing the same thing). Eclipse builds make me ... nervous. I'll certainly give it a go though, thanks.

Comment: I hear you there, but m2e regularly fills me with rage, so if I *really* need a breakpoint I suffer through the Eclipse build. That said, I'm keeping my eye on this question to see if there's a better way.

Comment: m2eclipse debugging works for me.. I did have to mess around with the 'Source' settings on the project, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are gonna want to run configure the MAVEN_OPTS to allow an external debugger and connect to it from eclipse as a Remote Java Application:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Debugging+with+the+Maven+Jetty+Plugin+inside+Eclipse

Comment: In the absence of a integrated solution, this might have to do! Thanks